# Combine items in list

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Python3:

```
dct = {'Mazda': [['Ford', 95], ['Toyota', 20], ['Chrysler', 52], ['Toyota', 5], ['Toyota', 26]]}
```

I have the above dictionary with the values being a list within a list. What I would like to do is combine the items within the list that are the same and add the integer to that value.

eg. since Toyota is in there 3x then combine all the numbers together to give me another list

```
[Toyota, 51]
```

Final result should be
does not need to be in this order

```
dct = {'Mazda': [['Ford', 95], ['Toyota', 51], ['Chrysler', 52]]}
```

Comment: If they car names end up being unique, you should make it a dict instead of a nested list.

Answer (score 3):

For the input in the question:

```
dct = {'Mazda': [['Ford', 95],  ['Toyota', 20], ['Chrysler', 52],
                 ['Toyota', 5], ['Toyota', 26]]}
```

Try this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

for k, v in dct.items():
    aux = defaultdict(int)
    for car, num in v:
        aux[car] += num
    dct[k] = map(list, aux.items())
```

Now `dct` contains the expected result:

```
dct
=> {'Mazda': [['Ford', 95], ['Toyota', 51], ['Chrysler', 52]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store two lists: one with car names and one with numbers. Iterate through the list in the dictionary, adding a new element to each list if the car isn't already there, or otherwise add the number to the car index. In the end, `zip()` the two lists together.

Answer (score 0):

```
dct = {'Mazda': [['Ford', 95], ['Toyota', 20], ['Chrysler', 52], ['Toyota', 5], ['Toyota', 26]]}

newdct = {}
for item in dct:
    newdct[item] = []
    unqItems = {}
    for val in dct[item]:
        if val[0] not in unqItems:
            unqItems[val[0]] = 0
        unqItems[val[0]] += val[1]
    for u in unqItems:
        newdct[item].append([u, unqItems[u]])
print newdct
```

Answer (score 0):

using `itertools.groupby()`:

```
In [66]: dct = {'Mazda': [['Ford', 95], ['Toyota', 20], ['Chrysler', 52], ['Toyota', 5], ['Toyota', 26]]}

In [67]: from itertools import groupby

In [68]: from operator import *

In [69]: dct = {'Mazda': [['Ford', 95], ['Toyota', 20], ['Chrysler', 52], ['Toyota', 5], ['Toyota', 26]]}

In [70]: { x: [[k,sum(y[1] for y in g)] for k,g in groupby(sorted(dct[x]),
                                              key=itemgetter(0))] for x in dct}

Out[70]: {'Mazda': [['Chrysler', 52], ['Ford', 95], ['Toyota', 51]]}
```